# C# SAML Parsing to XML to get the value of Audience

Tags: c#, xml, saml

I have tried several ways to parse the SAML

```
       string raw = txt.Text;
        if (raw.Contains('%'))
        {
            raw = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(raw);
        }
        byte[] xmlMessageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(raw);
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument { PreserveWhitespace = true };
        document.LoadXml(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xmlMessageBytes));
```

But I get random characters in the response. But when I use Firefox addon SAMLTracer it works perfectly fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless doing this for fun/to learn, I recommend you to not create your own SAML2 implementation. It is a lot of work and easy to get critical security mechanisms wrong (XML signature wrapping vulnerabilities are common in SAML implementations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the SAML message passed as a query string parameter? In that case it is using the Http Redirect binding and the message contents are deflate encoded.

For reference, this is the redirect decoding from the [Kentor.AuthServices](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices/blob/master/Kentor.AuthServices/WebSSO/Saml2RedirectBinding.cs#L83) library:

```
using (var compressed = new MemoryStream(payload))
{
  using (var decompressedStream = new DeflateStream(compressed, CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
  {
    using (var deCompressed = new MemoryStream())
    {
      decompressedStream.CopyTo(deCompressed);
      var xml = new XmlDocument()
      {
        PreserveWhitespace = true
      };

      xml.LoadXml(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(deCompressed.GetBuffer()));

      // Simplified, the real code does some more work.
      return xml;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, is there a way to get this working in 2.0 for some reasons it is not supported in 4.0 framework

Comment: Having issues with CopyTo in 2.0